# bash запускк скрипта и работа внутри него

Tags: linux, bash

Пишу скрипт по автоматизации. Стоит задача запустить программу metasploit (msfconsole), а затем вызывать команды в цикле внутри этой программы. По факту получается только запустить программу, а вот следующие команды уже не выполнются  (только после выхода из metasploit).
Как это все реализовать в bash скрипте?

Answer (score 1):

В msfconsole есть ключ -r, который позволяет запускать скрипт.

```
msfconsole -r script
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть [статью](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/writing-meterpreter-scripts/) на официальном сайте.

Comment: Спасибо! Это хороший вариант. Но хотелось бы запустить 1 раз msf и потом в цикле перебирать ip и к каждому применять run.

Comment: @boomuo ну так и делайте это же в script